# identifying the tag of a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my app the user can create many UIImageViews programmly, and tags are assigned successfully to all the ImageViews. Then, in the following way I detect (in this case through touches moved) the tag of the image, and according to the tag I change the color.

```
int touchedtag = touch.view.tag;

    NSUInteger tagCount = touchedtag;
    switch (tagCount) {
        case 1: 
            image1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        case 2: 
            image1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            break;
        case 3: 
            image1.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
            break;
        case 4: 
            image1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            break;
        default :

            break;

    }
```

as you can see there are 4 cases. But if the user creates 50 UIImageViews, do I need to create 50 cases, or it's possible to do this identification process with less code?? (CONSIDER THAT THE CHANGE OF COLOR IS TO SEE IF IT WORKS, BUT THEN THIS WILL BE ONLY USED TO IDENTIFY THE TAG)

Comment: you already have the imageview the touch originated in so what else are you trying to identify?  What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: Then you've already succeeded because you have the view.  If by selecting you mean giving it a border or a shadow or something then simply do so on your view object.  You can even store the view to a currentSelection variable or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 50 different `UIImageView` Tag you can also programable define your tag.

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < 50;i++)
{
     UIImageView *yourIMG = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
     yourIMG.tag = i;
}
```

And switch case them with their tag

For the 50 different color , you can customize the color to `UIImageView` with RGB parameter like this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:225 green:225 blue:225 alpha:1];
```

Try to use `for` loop to programmable adjust these parameter such increase red 2 unit or decrease blue 10 unit for each image

Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

Well if you were using just 1 color it would be easier, but if you want 50 different colors, yes you need to create 50 cases.

Comment: So to see if I understand, you just want to see the tag of a selected UIImage, right? If that's the case why don't you try with NSLog(@"tag: %d",tagCount); ?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to create 50 cases just to check a numeric value, or any cases at all for that matter.  What are you going to do with the tag value?  Assign an arbitrary color?

Either way, here is a replication of your example code without using a case statement.

```
NSArray *colors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor brownColor], [UIColor blackColor], nil];

NSUInteger touchedtag = touch.view.tag;
image1.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:touchedtag];
```

Of course if your tag is greater than the number colors in your array, you'll have a problem.  You can work that out with other logic, or just keep recycling through your array by changing the second line to:

```
NSUInteger touchedtag = touch.view.tag % colors.count;
```